# Can I use in hybrid-app for Android (via Cordova) a navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia to work with camera?

Tags: android, cordova

I create a web-app that used camera with

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()
```

In browser it works fine. But if I compile it for Android (in Cordova with Android Studio) - camera is not working in Android Emulator.

I try add:

1. cordova-plugin-camera to Cordova
2. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` to AndroidManifest.xml

but Emulator (API 22, Android 5.1) is not watching my local webcam on notebook

What can I do with it?

Is that really working with camera on `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` in hybrid-app or it is impossible at any way?

Thank you!

Comment: when you have installed `cordova-plugin-camera`, why not use that instead of `mediaDevices` ?

Comment: becouse I develope it in Vue.js, then convert into static pages (on Nuxt), then put it on "www" dir on Cordova, and compile to APK. and in Vue.js I do not testing and debugging work of "cordova-plugin-camera". it is pain :)

Comment: Cordova is framework independent. You are free to use any framework, just include cordova.js in your index.html

Comment: Really? Hmmm... And how can I use a Cordova plugins (cordova-plugin-camera) if I "just include cordova.js in my index.html"? Where can I found more information about it?

Comment: that how Cordova works mate, you need to move your files to `www` and in the `index.html`, need to include `cordova.js`. Do you need me to put in an answer as explanation?